# add title to ngx-mat-datetime-picker

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am building a small email scheduler app and I am using ngx-mat-datetime-picker for the user to choose a date. I need to  add a title to ngx-mat-datetime-picker popup.

```
<ngx-mat-datetime-picker  #picker [color]="color"
                                  [enableMeridian]="false"  >
          <mat-header-row>hello</mat-header-row>
          <ng-template>
            <button mat-button (click)="setScheduleTime()">OK</button>
          </ng-template>
        </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
```

is it possible to do that.?